# Table control with sliding row headers in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

The album view in iTunes has a slick effect where the album title and cover art stay in view at all times. If you slide down the screen they stay pinned to the top of the screen until they bump into the next album, then they slide away.

[image: iPad screenshot]

Notice how the top album is still fully visible even though the user has scrolled down a ways.

1. What is this control or effect called? I'm coming up with blanks trying to Google for it.
2. How can I do this in JavaFX? I want to mimic this in my Java-based GUI. Can TableView do this, or maybe some third-party control?

Comment: That effect is the normal behavior of a section header in a UITableView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with a ScrollPane. Inside your ScrollPane you define your rows and their layouts (probably each row is an HBox containing an ImageView and a TableView which is set to the height of the ImageView). Then, the TableViews inside your ScrollPane need to let the ScrollPane override their scrolling - that is, their onScroll bubbles up to the ScrollPane.

Then you override the onScroll behavior for your ScrollPane. The algorithm for the scrolling could go like this:

There are two modes.

1) Scrolling IN an album scrolls the TableView in that row. If the scrolling goes beyond the boundaries of the TableView's scrollHeight (the range between 0 and scrollHeight), then the mode switches to scrolling TO an album.

2) Scrolling TO an album scrolls the ScrollPane an amount up to the height of the current row. Scrolling an amount greater than the current row's height moves to the next album and switches the mode back to Scrolling IN that album.

3) Edge Cases: Scrolling within the ScrollPane beyond the boundaries of the ScrollPane's scrollHeight (the range between 0 and scrollHeight) immediately moves to the next album and switches the mode back to Scrolling IN that album.

I'd give a code example, but I've never actually seen anybody try to do this. I just know you CAN do it.

Comment: As a corollary, it looks like there are two scrollable panes in the iTunes case, as the left pane and the right pane are not the same heights. You could lock the scrolling of the TableViews in the right pane with the scrolling of the album art in the left pane, and instead of switching MODES, you could switch back and forth between which pane is scrolling at a given time. This would produce the same effect I described without requiring your panes to be the same size.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to take a look to the SpreadsheetView in [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#spreadsheetview)

The SpreadsheetView allow you to fix at the top of the screen any number of line. So you would have the first part of your behavior.

Regarding the fact of bumping into another, it would be more difficult but not impossible with the SpreadsheetView.

Anyway, if you want to implement that behavior in the TableView, you will find very useful tricks in the SpreadsheetView code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how a section title acts as default in a UITableView.

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html

This should help you on how to create and use UITableView

Comment: UITableView has the effect I like, but my target platform/API is the JavaFX GUI library in Java. I want to replicate UITableView's behavior there.